# How do I append tuples together?

Tags: python, tuples

I'm trying to put together multiple tuples but do not know how.  I know how to create a tuple, but I'm not quite sure how to put them together.  I want to keep on appending (not actually appending because I don't want a list).  I'm pulling a string out of each line and putting all of the tuples together

```
x = (132, 534, 4)
y = (345, 531, 1)
z = (212, 421, 5)
```

What I want returned

```
(132, 534, 4), (345, 531, 1), (212, 421, 5)
```

Comment: You want to merge them or create a tuple of tuple ?

Comment: I'm guessing you want some parentheses to encapsulate that floating list?

Comment: tuple of a tuple @jordsti

Comment: The use of a tuple and your intention to "keep on appending" are mutually exclusive. Only a list can be appended to.

Comment: It is indeed very unclear what exactly you want here. The text sounds like you want to concatenate the tuples- make them all into one single tuple- but the "what i want returned" looks more like a tuple of tuples, which is a very different thing. And of course there's the fact that it sounds like you have a significant design error in your code- if you want to add something to the data structure, you want a list, not a tuple.

Comment: You can "keep appending" to a tuple, but you'd really be creating a new object and destroying the old one each time it grows...inefficient.

Comment: While tuples look kinda-sorta like lists, tuples are meant for "record-like" rows of data that can be of varying types that wouldn't naturally grow. If you're storing a series of data, or a column of "field-like" things, use a list.

Answer (score 6):

The tuple in your example can be created like this:

```
>>> # The following line is equivalent to:  new_tuple = (x, y, z)
>>> new_tuple = x, y, z
>>> new_tuple
((132, 534, 4), (345, 531, 1), (212, 421, 5))
>>>
```

However, because tuples are immutable (cannot be changed after creation) sequences, you will need to create a new one each time you want to "append" to it:

```
>>> new_tuple = x, y, z
>>> new_tuple
((132, 534, 4), (345, 531, 1), (212, 421, 5))
>>> w = 1, 2, 3  # This is another tuple that needs to go inside new_tuple
>>> new_tuple = x, y, z, w  # So, we have to rebuild new_tuple to include it
>>> new_tuple
((132, 534, 4), (345, 531, 1), (212, 421, 5), (1, 2, 3))
>>>
```

This is why it would be best to just use a list, which is a mutable (can be changed after  creation) sequence that has an [`append`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) method:

```
>>> new_list = [x, y, z]  # Square brackets make a list
>>> new_list
[(132, 534, 4), (345, 531, 1), (212, 421, 5)]
>>> w = 1, 2, 3
>>> new_list.append(w)  # Add w to new_list without rebuilding it
>>> new_list
[(132, 534, 4), (345, 531, 1), (212, 421, 5), (1, 2, 3)]
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

the easiest way to do that may be this

```
x = (132, 534, 4)
y = (345, 531, 1)
z = (212, 421, 5)

r = x, y, z
```

Comment: Why `z, y, x`? That should be `x, y, z` - but then how would you "keep on appending" to it (as the OP wants to do)?